# Mocha Regexp length calculation in loop does not work

Tags: javascript, regex, mocha.js

Regexp length calculation in loop does not work in mocha.

```
function getData() {
const files = getAllFilePathsWithExtension(process.cwd(), 'js');
const reg = /\/\/ ?TODO ?.+/gi;
    for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        let text = readFile(files[i]);
        let find = text.match(reg);

        find.length
    }
}
```

I have an error:

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/user/...)

But if you remove one line, it works:

```
function getData() {
const files = getAllFilePathsWithExtension(process.cwd(), 'js');
const reg = /\/\/ ?TODO ?.+/gi;
    for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        let text = readFile(files[i]);
        let find = text.match(reg);

        //find.length
    }
}
```

How do i make it work?

Comment: Did you mean to `return find.length`? Right now your function doesn't return a result. Also, you have `find.length` inside the loop. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: An error occurs even when the result is returned. ''find"" gets a two-dimensional array, and counting the length of the array does not allow to pass the test. Counting the length of the array is the problem